# Laravel/Eloquent whereHas with all items in relation?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Models Song and Writer

And I want to query songs such that I only get songs where **ALL** its writers have a certain field that is true, what would my solution be?

The Laravel whereHas function will get all songs that have **at least one** writer with that field, like so.

```
Song::whereHas('writers', function($query){
    $query->where('writerField', '=', true);
});
```

But what is the pure eloquent way to make sure **ALL** writer related to a Song has that 'writerField' set to true?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Invert your constraint, and pass the desired count to the `whereHas` method:

```
Song::whereHas('writers', function() {
    $query->where('writerField', false);
}, '=', 0);
```

Comment: Perfect. Accepted answer. Thank you.