# Projects and tasks: only get projects where all tasks are active

Tags: laravel

I have two models: Project and Task.

Both have a relationship with each other set in their models.

Tasks have a progress status of in_progress (1) or completed (0).

Using relationships, i am trying to only get projects that only have tasks that are completed.

Right now, with my code, i get projects that have at least one task completed.

Thanks for your help!

```
public function completedtasks()
    {
        return $this->hasmany(Task::class)->whereStatus_id(1)->whereProgress_id(0);
    }
```

Comment: Do you need projects which has all task completed?

Comment: That is correct, projects with all tasks completed.

Comment: whats difference between status_id and progress_id

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should approach this in an different way:

Create your relationship method in your Project:

```
/**
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function tasks(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

Then you can filter your projects like this:

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('tasks', function($query) {
    return $query->where('progress_id', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. The thing is, it also returns projects that have other tasks with progress_id of 0. Maybe i should add an additional function to exclude tasks that have a progress_id of 0...

Comment: Just read this answer (No time to test it but I think this may be also your solution) https://stackoverflow.com/a/32639115/7946215

Answer (score 0):

You could get all projects that do not have any Tasks with `progress_id = 0`. Then you can also check that the project has any Tasks with `progress_id = 1` (completed). [Project must not have any Tasks with `progess_id = 0` and must have at least 1 Task with `progress_id = 1`]

```
Project::whereDoesntHave('tasks', function ($query) {
    $query->where('progress_id', 0);
})->whereHas('tasks', function ($query) {
    $query->where('progress_id', 1);
})->get();
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Querying Relationship Absense](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) - `whereDoesntHave`

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) - `whereHas`